# sleep() causes segmentation fault

Tags: c++

I have a dynamic library with a header file as follows:

```
#ifndef SRC_H
#define SRC_H

#include<time.h>

namespace test
{
    void sleep( int numsec );
}
#endif
```

and a source file as follows:

```
#include"src.h"

namespace test
{
    void sleep(int numsec)
    {
        sleep(numsec);        
    }
}
```

And I have an executable consisting only only of the following main file

```
#include "linked/src.h"

int main() 
{
    test::sleep(3);    
}
```

And I get

> Starting program: /usr0/home/gschoenh/Dropbox/Code/cpp/scratch/main/app
>   [Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
>   Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
>
> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
>   0x00007ffff7bd863c in test::sleep (numsec=3) at src.cpp:8
>   8           sleep(numsec);

Thank you for your help :)

PS: I have spent a lot of time trying to solve this on my own. I have solved my last 100 bugs on my own. So please no flame comments like "You ^#*$(#($&%(#_. Spend more time trying to do it youself you #*$&@*(#)@." Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

```
void sleep(int numsec)
{
    sleep(numsec);        
}
```

Looks like a recursive infinite loop. It's likely to cause a stack overflow unless your compiler does tail recursion elimination.

If that's suppose to be a call to the POSIX `sleep` function, it's declared in `<unistd.h>`. You should be able to call it like this, once you add `#include <unistd.h>`:

```
::sleep(numsec);
```

Comment: Indeed, the call to sleep in test::sleep is supposed to call the POSIX function. It seems that what you are saying is that in the declaration of test::sleep, the namespace "test" is automatically used, so sleep() is overridden by test::sleep(). If that is so, that would be a very useful thing to know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
void sleep(int secs)
{
sleep(3);
}
```

Above code leads to infinite recursion. I modified the code such as:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
void sleep(int secs)
{
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
cout << "Before sleep\n";
::sleep(3);
cout << "After sleep" << endl;
}
```

It fine for me, g++ compiler version g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3

Also as per **Linux** man pages http://linux.die.net/man/3/sleep; sleep prototype is

```
unsigned int sleep(unsigned int secs)
```

You can also modify the code to store return from sleep (unistd.h) in to a dummy to resolve the conflict as well check the return value (say if call was interrupted by signals).